# Basic Geometry: Triangles

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to find an easy way to solve the problem below:

[image: basic geometry problem]

Of course you could solve it by "brute force", example:
- numerical means (vectors and dot product), or
- long algebra calculations (law of sines/cosines and trigonometric identities).

However, considering this was a question in a high school exam (3~5 min per question), most likely there is a shortcut. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Introduce isosceles $\triangle PAB$, then chase some angles:

[image]

Comment: Impressive! Mind to explain a little bit how did you come up with that? And how long did you take to 'see' this solution?

Comment: Also, how hard did you consider this problem to be? Do you think it is reasonable to be in a high school exam designed for 3~5 minutes per question?

Comment: Well, I have to admit, it took a bit longer than $3$-$5$ minutes, but I was exploring multiple trigonometric approaches to see if I could distill them to something self-evident. I had a sense that $\angle ADC = 60^\circ$ (which is easy to determine) was key, and I fairly quickly introduced $30^\circ$-$60^\circ$-$90^\circ$ $\triangle PDC$. I could then show that $\overline{AP}\cong\overline{CP}$ with trig, which solved the problem. Starting a little longer at the diagram made me realize that $P$ was actually the circumcenter, and the self-evident decomposition fell into place. (continued)

Comment: > "P was actually the circumcenter" This was the main point I was hoping to hear ... whether you started considering the circumcenter was key or if there was something else that trigger this ...

Comment: (continuing) I certainly wouldn't expect someone to derive my angle-chasing solution on a time-constrained exam. I'll note that my trig approach, upon creating $\triangle PDC$, was roughly: Let $\triangle ABP$ have circumdiameter $1$, then $|BD|=|PD|=\frac12|CD| = \sin 15^\circ$, and $|AD| = \sin 45^\circ$, so that $$|AP| = \sin 45^\circ - \sin 15^\circ = 2\cos 30^\circ \sin 15^\circ = |CD|\cos 30^\circ = |CP|$$ That might still require a little more inspiration than exam conditions allow. You should ask the instructor what the "expected" solution was supposed to be ... and report back here!

Comment: To answer your specific question: I didn't actually think about the fact that $P$ was the circumcenter until I needed a concise way to describe it in these limited-character comments. :)

Comment: _"until I needed a concise way to describe it"_ Ok, the first time I've watched your answer with the circumcenter I've thought you were some kind of [Will Hunting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_Will_Hunting). However, even without realizing it at first, you are a genius nonetheless! :-)

Comment: Whoops. Typo in my trigonometric solution; it should read: Let $\triangle ABD$ have circumdiameter $1$, then ...